# Do employers look at master's program grades and GPA?

Tags: resume, united-states

I just completed the requirements for my two-year master's program. I absolutely hated my master's program experience as it felt like an arduous DIY program where I felt as if most of the professors were there only to grade, not to teach or help students. I just received my last semester grades, and one of my grades is bad. This class was a group project class and involved working on a two-semester long project and presentation. My former group of five people was very dysfunctional and classless. Even though we were all master's students, a number of them (two that I did not get along with) would swear constantly and say many insensitive things. Their language use perhaps, also played a major role in my participation, but I still contributed to the group. I do not plan to mention this group project work in my resume or interviews not because of my negative experience, but also because the topic became obsolete during the second semester that we worked on it.

**Even though I have my undergraduate GPA on my resume, I do not plan to include my graduate school GPA on my resume even though it is not bad (but lower than what I had expected). Would employers care about my master's program GPA since it is the highest level of education that I attained?**

Comment: The answer depends on the industry and company. The question can't be answered in general terms.

Answer (score 4):

> Would employers care about my master's program GPA since it is the
>   highest level of education that I attained?

I think, based on my experience, most will not care about the actual grade but will be looking at the fact you have a Master's as a **plus** in most cases.

Having said that, there will *always* be companies who will look at the transcript and judge a candidate partially on grades.  There is nothing you can do about this and no way for you to know who will and won't care about the grade.

My best advise to you is when and if you are asked about the grade, just be open and honest about it and remember a Masters is a great achievement!

Comment: agreed, it really depends on the job. Prior experiece + masters is v. strong, and i've seen people get into Mckinsey with a rubbish masters but they had strong prior work experience. Also depends where your masters is from - a masters from, say, Harvard, well, the GPA won't matter so much.

Comment: Yep, this has been my experience. I've also found that some companies will ask for GPA and even transcripts from all colleges on their applications as a matter of course, but nobody actually asks about it during interviews.

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks suspicious to someone reviewing a resume if you include the GPA from the Bachelor's degree but not the other.  Either include both or include neither.

Next, whether a company will care is not something we can predict. Some will, some won't. The ones likely to care the most are going to ask for a transcript.  And the GPA is pretty irrelevant if you have job experience.

There are plenty of good companies that won't care about your GPA. You simply need to sell yourself based on something else.

As a side note, there will be plenty of people you don't like that you will have to work with. Learn to do so. It is a career killer to not be able to work with whoever you need to be able to work with. You deserved that low grade if you couldn't do it for a class. That was part of what you were supposed to be learning.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more complicated than it appears.

If you get bothered by people using foul language, you want to be very careful in the interview process, because if you end up in a workplace with people who cuss, you're going to have a bad time.

Your goal should be to find a cultural fit: a manager who also gets pissy when people use foul language. Personally, I make sure to toss out a few foul words when I interview, because I want the exact opposite.

Such a manager is also likely to care about your grades. A manager who doesn't care about your grades also won't give a fuck about your language.

Comment: I do not believe that last statement is true. I know of plenty of managers who would find swear words in the office totally unprofessional (especially if clients/customers are sometimes present in the offices) who don't care about grades.